# Sublime Text 2 - Defining constants in a project

Tags: sublimetext2

I am trying to use Phpcs in a Sublime Text 2 project.

I am following a tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/psr-duh--net-31061). It says that it should put the code below in *Setting - User*

```
{
    "phpcs_additional_args": {
        "--standard": "PSR2",
        "-n": ""
    },
    "phpcs_executable_path": "DEPENDENCY_PATH/vendor/bin/phpcs",
    "phpmd_executable_path": "DEPENDENCY_PATH/vendor/bin/phpmd",
    "php_cs_fixer_executable_path": "DEPENDENCY_PATH/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer"
}
```

The question is, where do I define the `DEPENDENCY_PATH` constant?

I want this to be a on a per project basis. So is it even correct to define this in *Setting - User*?

**EDIT:** I am on Windows 8

Comment: Quoted from same page: "Don't forget to replace DEPENDENCY_PATH with your actual path.". It's the path of composer.json you just created for dependencies.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that further. Is it the full or relative folder path where the composer.json resides? Are these settings also be only on a per project basis(that is, can it be saved in .sublime-project file)?

Comment: It's the full path. Phpcs needs those executables. It has nothing to do with your projects (At least that's what I got from tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "phpcs_additional_args": {
        "--standard": "PSR2",
        "-n": ""
    },
    "phpcs_executable_path": "DEPENDENCY_PATH/vendor/bin/phpcs",
    "phpmd_executable_path": "DEPENDENCY_PATH/vendor/bin/phpmd",
    "php_cs_fixer_executable_path": "DEPENDENCY_PATH/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer"
}
```

Just below this code block in the article it says that you should replace **DEPENDENCY_PATH** with your **actual path**. The foloowing paragraph reads as:

*These settings inform PHPCS that we want to ahere to the PSR2 standard and provide each dependency's path. Don't forget to **replace DEPENDENCY_PATH with your actual path**.*